# Factory - Then and Catch Promise Chaining in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, promise, angular-promise

I came across this tricky scenario when to chain promises inside factory or to take it over to the controller.

Couple of questions for the same:

- Which one is beneficial? Writing **then** and **catch** inside the factory function or in controller.
- Business Scenario
- Performance Advantage

Earlier I used to write the then and catch chaining like this inside a factory method:

```
function searchReservations(lastName, arrivalDate)
    {
       // alert(lastName + ' ' + arrivalDate)

          return $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: baseUrl + '/reservation?lastName='+lastName+'&arrivalDate='+arrivalDate
          })
            **.then(success)
            .catch(failure);**

          function success(response) {
            return response;
          }

          function failure(error) {
            console.log('XHR Failed for searchReservation' + error.data);
            return error;
          }
    }
```

But as a new trend, I saw then and catch being written both in the controller function. Somewhat like this.

```
HRS.searchReservations(this.searchLastName, arrivalDate).then(function(response) {
...
}).catch(function(response){
...
})
```

More specifically on business case and performance advantage I would like to know the difference here.

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: Unrelated to the question, try observing code and not coders. You convolute your knowledge when you apply someone else's experience - though I understand that someone else's experience is the most sought-after commodity in today's 'job market' so I can understand if you prefer to seek the latest coding trends

Comment: One advantage I see of the second way is readability/encapsulation - you are talking to your service always in terms of a 'promise' without knowing how its implemented - it may be serving a constant or an ajax call or making a database call.  And the service just exposes the 'promise' interface without the callbacks.  Your 'controller' should know how to 'consume' this.  If there's data manipulation inside success/failure callback is going to be repeated, then the first approach of keeping it inside the 'service' might make sense.

Comment: For second scenario, good details - any advantage in terms of performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the first. I find it's cleaner, easier to read, and allows you to name your methods to give them added clarity.

In services, my success and error functions transform response data into the view-model format that will be used by my controller.

Then in my controller, I also have a success and error function to handle displaying that output in a meaningful way. But the controller is only interested in displaying of the data, where the service handles any transformations, localStorage, etc.

Also, if you have a failure method in your service, you need to `return $q.reject(error)` if you want it to trigger the catch function of your controller.

Side note, you can use `params: ...` to easily and cleanly attach query parameters to your url:

```
{
  method: 'GET',
  url: baseUrl + '/reservation',
  params: {
    lastName: lastName, 
    arrivalDate: arrivalDate
  }
}
```

How I like to structure the service methods:

```
function searchReservations (lastName, arrivalDate) {
  var config = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: baseUrl + '/reservation',
    params: {
      lastName: lastName, 
      arrivalDate: arrivalDate
    }
  };
  return $http(config).then(success).catch(error);

  ////////////

  function success (response) {
    return response;
  }

  function error (response) {
    console.log('XHR Failed for searchReservation' + response.data);
    return $q.reject(response);
  }
}
```

Note, in this case you don't even need a `success` method because it doesn't do anything, so you can skip it completely like so: `return $http(config).catch(error)`. Any `.then(...)` on your controller will still be triggered.

Comment: Good detailed answer. Any advantage or comments on performance?

Comment: No, it's purely about code readability, so that it's easy for future developers to read and follow. We place more importance on maintainability than shaving a few milliseconds from performance.